# When are statements executed in a module?

Tags: python

I've started to see a few constructs like this:

```
class Foo:
     def someFunc1:
          ...
     def someFunc2:
          ...

     bar = 2 + 2

     def someFunc3:
          ...
```

When would `bar` get executed in this example?

Comment: Before `someFunc3` is defined (and before the definition of `Foo` finishes) but after `someFunc2` is defined. It's conventional to put class attributes before method definitions, unless there's some good reason otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Upon class declaration when the module is loaded:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def someFunc1(self):
...         pass
...     def someFunc2(self):
...         pass
...     bar = 2 + 2
...     def someFunc3(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> Foo.bar
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`bar` in this case would be considered a class attribute. It is accessible as a property of the class itself and to instances of the class:

Here are two examples to help you understand.

Accessing as a property of the class:

```
class Foo(object):
    stuff = "hello"

Foo.stuff # will hold hello
```

Accessing as an instance of the class:

```
f = Foo()
f.stuff # will hold "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is a class variable and it gets executed at the class definition time i.e. at the module level.

From the [Class Definition docs:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions)

> **A class definition is an executable statement**. It first evaluates the
>   inheritance list, if present. Each item in the inheritance list should
>   evaluate to a class object or class type which allows subclassing. The
>   class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame, using a newly created local namespace and the
>   original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function
>   definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution
>   frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. **A class
>   object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes
>   and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.** The class
>   name is bound to this class object in the original local namespace.
>
> **When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and
>   used as the local scope — thus, all assignments to local variables go
>   into this new namespace.**

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
   .....:     bar = 1
   .....:     

In [2]: Foo.__dict__
Out[2]: <dictproxy {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
        '__doc__': None,
        '__module__': '__main__',
        '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,
         'bar': 1}> # bar class variable

In [3]: Foo.bar
Out[3]: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

After an object has been created from the class it would be executed when the object's attribute 'bar' is called.

```
class Foo():
     def someFunc1():
        pass

     def someFunc2():
        pass

     bar = 2 + 2

     def someFunc3():
        pass

obj = Foo()
print(obj.bar)
```

If no object is created from the class then it can be accessed from the class directly:

```
class Foo():
     def someFunc1():
        pass

     def someFunc2():
        pass

     bar = 2 + 2

     def someFunc3():
        pass


print(Foo.bar)
```